# slick slider is not loading completely

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, slick.js

```js
 $('.vendor_slider_fixed ').slick({
    dots: false,
    arrows:false,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3 
  });
```

Here I have shared screenshot I have implemented slick slider on my website but it showing unexpected behavior after one time scroll it works completely perfect Can you please help me to get rid of this issue? any help would be appreciated
https://prnt.sc/26np6ld

Comment: Please share your [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @DarkBee please see above code

Comment: Should add  the relevant HTML as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reinitialize it by adding reInit or some other parameter/method. https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/